# python sqlite3 query with AND

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to build a simple Address book GUI that has a `wx.listbox`, that holds all the names in the book, first and last. Once clicked, it will return the information attached to the name from a database file. Right now I have it working by just the last name, I am trying to match first and last names. I am not, really, familiar with the SQLite 3 commands and syntax.

The function is below, this works fine now, but I want to change the query to something like:

```
select * from AddressBook where Last like names[0] and First like names[1]
```

Any help would be great!

```
def onListBox(self, event):
    name  =  event.GetEventObject().GetStringSelection()
    names = name.split(',')###names[0]=Last name, names[1] = first name
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from AddressBook where Last like ?",('%'+names[0]+'%',) )
    result  =  cursor.fetchall()
    return result
```

Comment: Did you try that query?

Comment: Did you try just adding that second parameter to the query?

Comment: yeah,  it comes back with a  syntax error

Comment: Are you sure that query should be returning anything?  What happens when you run it directly on SQLite?

Comment: "select * from AddressBook where Last = ? and First = ?", ('%'+names[0]+'%','%'+names[1]+'%') )  
returns nothing, no error

Comment: Can you get rid of the stray comma: `('%'+names[0]+'%')` ?

Comment: if I remove the comma from the original query, it throws  sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 11 supplied.

Comment: "select * from AddressBook where Last = ? and First = ?" is obviously incorrect, what if you just replace "=" with "like" ?

Comment: it wont return anything from that

Comment: What is the value of `names[0]` and how many columns are in the `AddressBook` table?

Comment: Please show the code from your attempt at implementing the query with the AND clause, and post the traceback of the syntax error.

Comment: There was no error with the AND clause, it just returns nothing, in sqlite3 command line and python code
'SELECT * FROM AddressBook WHERE First like ? and Last like ?',('%'+names[0]+'%','%'+names[1]+'%')

Comment: Looks like I had a white space in one of the names, thats why it wasnt matching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query from your comment should work.

Here is a small working example:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.sql")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("create table address_book (first_name text, last_name text)")
names = [["John", "Smith"], ["Jane", "Smith"]]

for first_name, last_name in names:
    cursor.execute("insert into address_book (first_name, last_name) values (?, ?)", (first_name, last_name))

cursor.execute("select * from address_book where first_name like ? and last_name like ?", ("%" + names[0][0] + "%", "%" + names[0][1] + "%"))
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

It prints:

```
[('John', 'Smith')]
```